# JQuery plugin options assignment syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm trying to add options to my first ever jquery plugin, but I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : weather2.js:6

My plugin code looks something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        weather: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                cityName : "Johannesburg"; // required
                mainImage : ""; // required
                jhbImage : ""; // required
                dbnImage : ""; // required
                cptImage : ""; // required
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                // plugin logic goes here.
                // options are referenced with options.optionName (eg. options.cityName)
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

The error makes me feel like I should be substituting the colon in the assignments with an equal to same way as `var defaults` is declared, but every tutorial I've seen suggests that this, too, would be incorrect.

Can anyone provide some clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your semicolons for commas in your object literal :)

```
        var defaults = {
            cityName: "Johannesburg",
            mainImage: "",
            jhbImage: "",
            dbnImage: "",
            cptImage: ""
        };
```

Comment: I hate when it's simple things like this... Thanks m8 :)

Comment: Agreed, it´s always the simple things that hurts you

Answer (score 0):

use commas instead of semicolon in defaults variable.